# Saddle Position

Tags: bike-fit, saddle, seatpost

I am a newbie to biking. I got my bike fitted in a local bike shop. I feel comfortable riding it. However, I feel (by looking at it) that the saddle is fitted way too back. It looks as if the back portion of the saddle is not supported very well because it is being held at an extreme position. Is this cause for concern? Should I go to the shop to get it changed? Please see the attached pictures.

Thanks

[image: Saddle Position]

[image: Saddle Position Other View]

Comment: Depending on your weight and riding style I’d be a bit concerned about the saddle rails breaking. The position looks extreme but could still be okay.

Comment: I am heavy - 220 lbs! Makes me scared then.

Comment: So long as the clamp is positioned on the horizontal part of the rails then it's "OK".  It is a bit more stressful on the rails having them positioned as shown, but the saddle should hold up reasonably well.

Comment: I'll note that you have a shock-absorbing post, and that removes some of the stress from the rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bike shop knows what they are doing, this might be the saddle position that gives you the best riding position. In this case, you have to choose between comfortable position and minimizing the risk of breaking saddle rails. Moving the saddle forward will put more weight on your arms and less room. Another odd thing in the saddle position is that it is quite sloped forward.

Usually the saddle is set close to horizontal and close to the center of the rails, unless there is a good reason to do otherwise. It's difficult to tell if there is without seeing you ride the bike.

Comment: Adding what we know together: Saddle very far back on rails, nose pointed a long way down, and a LOT of seat post showing, this looks very much to me like trying to fit a rider on a frame that is at least one size to small for them.  The extreme angle of the saddle is probably because the bars are a lot lower than the saddle.

Comment: Me says, botched fitting! And selling you a bike with V-brakes, not exactly the freshest salad in the store.

Comment: Everything in the photo points to low budget. So the question is, should the shop do their best to make the bike fit or just give up if the customer doesn't want or can't afford a new bike.

Comment: @Carel OP just said fitting in a bike shop, judging by the rust showing on the cables and nut heads I’d say it was a second hand bike and the OP was purely looking for a better fit, in which the case the shop has probably done their best by the OP.

Comment: Yes, the bike shop simply fitted the bike for me. I got this bike few years back online - I know, very bad idea!. Never really got the time to ride it. Wanted to ride this summer - actually wanted to sell this one and get a new bike. But, due to the COVID-19 bike stockout, couldn't get any. Bike shop guys told me that this is one size small for me - so you guys got it perfectly right. Now, the question really comes to should I keep riding it - it feels comfortable and I am riding about 20-30 miles per week-, or should I change that saddle position.